# How to return auth Token from .Net Core [Authorize] method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, openid-connect

My main application delegates authentication to an AuthService application, asking it to authenticate against an Identity Provider through OpenId Connect and return a token.

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet("Login")]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return Ok(
        {
            Token = ?
        }, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }
```

I have an API method with the `[Authorize]` attribute. The user is prompted to login if not already authenticated and then the method runs. My question is can I access the token from there so I can pass it in the response?

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I've come up with after looking through the suggestions here:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("Login")]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = $"{HttpContext.Request.PathBase.Value}/GetToken"
        }, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    }

    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    [HttpGet("GetToken")]
    public IActionResult GetToken()
    {
        var token = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "id_token").Result;

        return Ok(new
        {
            Token = token
        });
    }
```

I combined two APIs. From the perspective of the client app it makes a call to a Login API and gets the token as the result. Behind the scenes the Login API redirects to a second API to get and return the token.

UPDATE:

Revisting this after a while in case anyone sees this. I don't remember exactly how, but I think there was a problem with above approach for me.

In the end I used the `OnSignedIn` `CookieAuthenticationHandler` event to intercept the token and returned it with the response in a Cookie. The Login API still returns a `Challenge` request.

Answer (score 1):

You can get that information injecting a `IHttpContextAccessor` service in the controller and defining the service in the startup.cs class

```
public class HomeController
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public HomeController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        //check the _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext object for information about the already logged user
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
}
```

Comment: Where can I find it in the HttpContextAccessor - I've looked at AuthenticateAsync and GetTokenAsync but I don't know the name of the token.

Comment: FYI - I found it under HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "id_token").Result;

Comment: Great! hope it helps. If my answer help you solve your issue remember to tick it

Answer (score 0):

The [Authorize] attribute you are putting on the method means that you are restricting access to the method to authorised users only, so putting that attribute on a Login method makes no sense, as you would have to be authenticated to call it.

What you are looking for is

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
    }
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
    }
}
```

As for how to generate a token, you need to have an identity provider to take a username and password, validate it and create a token that has roles and privs.

I would suggest having a look at [Identity Server 4](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to generate tokens.

For info on how to connect it to OpenID see [Adding User Authentication with OpenID Connect](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html)

Comment: When I use the [Authorize] attribute unauthenticated users are prompted to login. I'm wired up using OIDC already and it returns a token somewhere. 

My question is how to access it from the API method.

Answer (score 0):

you must get a token to access the Authorize attribute method.

reference
[this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/authentication-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core-web-api-with-json-web-tokens/)